# Easiest way to go to start/end of html element

Tags: vimrc, filetype-html

I seem to be using a hack approach to getting to the start of an html tag. For example:

[image]

To get to my cursor to be on the `t` after the tag, I end up doing `yit` -- this yanks the component (which I don't care about). Is there a way to just do something like "it" to get to that `t` without doing anything (also doing `ft` gets me stuck at the `t` before so that becomes a hassle). And then, what about going to the end of the text, that is the 't' right before the `</td>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although vim provides text objects for tags, it doesn't have motions for tags.
One options is to reuse `it` to create a pair of maps `[t` and `]t` somewhat analogous to `[b`:

```
nnoremap [t vit<esc>`<
nnoremap ]t vit<esc>`>
```

These both work by temporarily visually selecting the inner tag and then moving to the start and end of the visual selection.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the optional plugin `:h matchit` , it's an extension for the built in `:h %` .

Add this to your vimrc and restart vim.

```
packadd! matchit
```

Now you can jump between `<td>` and `<\td>` by `%`, note you must not place your cursor at `<` or `>` for this to work, otherwise it jump between `<` and `>`

If you are in the body and you want to jump to the open or close tag, use `[%` or `]%`.

**If you want to go to start of the inner body**, use `[%%l`, `[%` jump to `<` of `<td>`, `%` jump to `>`. use `]%%h` for the other direction.

There is also Mass's [vim-matchup](https://github.com/andymass/vim-matchup) , it provides highlight, more motions, and textobjects.

Comment: The question is actually how to move to the start of the *contents* inside the tags... OP mentions using `yit` as having that side effect (leaving you at the beginning of the yanked area), but how to do it without having to yank it into a register?

Comment: @filbranden oops, updated.